# Inferred Property when integrating facebook like

Tags: facebook-like

I have done my research on this site, and found some great insight, however nothing has resolved my issue. I have a team of coding specialists that have been adding the FB Like metaproperties to each of our landing pages, however when we try to incorporate the LIKE button, it pulls the wrong content from the landing page. Here is the code we're putting:

```
<html><!-- #BeginTemplate "/Templates/<redacted>" --><!-- DW6 -->
<head>
<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->
<title>Jamaica Vacations with <redacted></title>
<!--
<meta property="og:title" name="og:title" content="Jamaica Vacations with <redacted>" />
<meta property="og:description" name="og:description" content="Get away to All-inclusive Jamaica! 3 nights from $354 per person!*" />
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="<redacted>/images/email/20120201-enews-caribbean-image02a.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<redacted>" />
```

-->

Sorry for the redacted portions, however I only removed company information. All other code is supplied "as is". When we run the landing page through the Facebook scraper located here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug It tells me:

Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The og:description property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

And it's pulling NONE of the metaproperties we set. This has been going for the past couple weeks, and people are getting anxious. Is there ANYONE in the cybersphere at stackoverflow that can help? I'll be happy to donate to your cause if you can help. Thank you and I'm happy to provide any other information!

Tim

Comment: The only bribes you can make for us is to give credit to the correct answer by clicking the grey checkmark beside the correct answer.  :)

Comment: I would suggest looking at the bottom of the linter tool for the link to see exactly what the linter sees.  That should give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you pointing your `og:url` to another URL which doesn't have the meta tags? Facebook will follow redirects, including the `og:url` tag which should point to the canonical URL of the content